# SQL not Selecting all rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to go through this entire table and echo out all of the emails

Here is my query

> SELECT `meta_value` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key`='user_email'

Here is a picture of when I execute it in Phpmyadmin

[image]

And here is the output when I run my php script

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "781"
  ["umeta_id"]=>
  string(3) "781"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "36"
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(2) "36"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "user_email"
  ["meta_key"]=>
  string(10) "user_email"
  [3]=>
  string(22) "ndroyal@eagleray.co.il"
  ["meta_value"]=>
  string(22) "ndroyal@eagleray.co.il"
}
```

You can clearly see there is way more than 8 rows, I can't figure this out any input would be greatly appreciated!

```
$data = $db->fetch_array("SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key`='user_email'");
var_dump($data);
```

DB Class:

```
<?php
class DB {

    function __construct() {
        global $dbase;
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($dbase['host'], $dbase['user'], $dbase['pass'], $dbase['name']);
        if($this->mysql->connect_error) {
            die('Unable to Connect to Database');
        }
    }
    function query($i) {
        return $this->mysqli->query($i);
    }
    function fetch_array($i) {
        if(!is_object($i)) {
            // create $i as an object!
            $i = $this->query($i);
        }
        return $i->fetch_array();
    }
    function num($i) {
        if(!is_object($i)) {
            // create $i as an object!
            $i = $this->query($i);
        }
        return $i->num_rows;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You are a genius if you show your PHP script.

Comment: Updated post with script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$db->fetch_array` only returns the first row of the result. You have to use a different method to loop through all selected rows, though you'll have to figure out which method that is on your own since we don't know your database class (of which $db is an instance of).

edit: The following code should work:

```
$result = $db->query(your query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

Comment: I've added my DB class to the post

Comment: Thank you so much ! That did the trick! Is there a way I could get 2 meta_value 's from different values such as, if I wanted the first_name row also

Comment: You likely have to grab that information from a different table. You can do this in the same query if you want to, e.g. `SELECT table1.name, table2.email FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id=<your id> AND table2.id=table1.id` (The syntax might be a little bit different, check the official documentation)